# Windows: Find specified filetypes and copy them to a Specified Directory

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

Imagine the following situation: You have a computer with lots of files on it. You need to have specific filetypes, but these could be anywhere on the PC, since there are multiple partitions.

Now I need to have a batch script where I can specify what to copy and what to **not** copy. Photo's, Pictures, Music, for example. I only need some specific filetypes, and it is nice to limit the size also. (Bigger then 1MB != NOT Copy). I have thought on programs like XCopy or Robocopy. The PC has Windows 7 Installed, but since I want to go native, please use no PowerShell answers. This is for learning purposes.

After that, copy all the files to a specified directory.

Any examples? The other answers around is just -not- exactly where I am looking for.

Edit1: If possible, it would be -very- nice to keep the Directory Structure.

Comment: robocopy supports size limits (/max) & excluding files (/xf) & directories (/xd) by name, whats the problem with it?

Comment: I agree with Alex K. It is tough to imagine a scenario where ROBOCOPY will not meet your needs. Also, PowerShell ***is*** native to Windows 7. But I still think ROBOCOPY is your best bet.

Comment: @AlexK. make that an answer and I will upvote you.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Alex K., robocopy is Windows native and will work as desired. Here is an example copying only *.jpg files:

```
robocopy *.jpg c:\destinationdir /S /MAX:1048576
```

This example excludes files that contain the name wedding:

```
robocopy *.jpg c:\destinationdir /S /MAX:1048576 /XF *wedding*
```

You can also do this in Vbscript which is Windows native on all versions since NT4 using the FSO filesystem object:

http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/filesystemobject_copyfile.html